# retrieve single custom field of custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type with a custom field created with Advanced Custom Fields. I can retrieve all of the posts of this type and display the images with the following code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'image' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $image = get_field('image_file'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

However, I want to be able to retrieve a single image url without looping through all of them. How would I go about this?

I've tried this:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'image', 'title' => 'Welcome to bird - image 1' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $image = get_field('image_file'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But it outputs the entire list - how can I just get a single post? If it helps, the permalink is like this:

```
/?image=welcome-to-bird-image-1
```

Comment: In the second example, why don't you use WP_Query again ?

Comment: Ah yes, I should. I've updated it but I still don't receive the single post - it displays all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now found the solution:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'image', 'image' => 'welcome-to-bird-image-3' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $image = get_field('image_file'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Filtering by 'image' worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use the X_posts table columns names as arguments in the WP_Query class in order to filter your database posts.

The only solution is to use the posts_where filter and then to apply regular MySQL code to filter the posts. Something like that:

```
function filter_where_title($where = '')
{
    $where .= " OR post_title LIKE '%" . $your_term_here . "%'";                   
    return $where;
}

$posts = new WP_Query();

add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where_title');
```

**Note :** The above example is general, and you have to apply extra code in order to strict the filtering in your custom post records only. The above code can affect other post types queries too.